# Group XML Key Tag with Same value using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Need help here in one of the query regarding parsing XML code via XSLT. Below is an example of the XML code i've.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Entity>
   <Shipment>
        <shipFromLocation>06AC001</shipFromLocation>
        <shipToLocation>07BCDAZ</shipToLocation>
        <container>
            <key1>101</key1>
            <key1>102</key1>
        </container>
        <container>
            <key1>103</key1>
            <key1>104</key1>
        </container>
   </Shipment>
   <Shipment>
        <shipFromLocation>06AC001</shipFromLocation>
        <shipToLocation>07BCDAZ</shipToLocation>
        <container>
            <key1>105</key1>
            <key1>106</key1>
        </container>
        <container>
            <key1>107</key1>
            <key1>108</key1>
        </container>
   </Shipment>
   <Shipment>
        <shipFromLocation>06AC002</shipFromLocation>
        <shipToLocation>08BCDAZ</shipToLocation>
        <container>
            <key1>200</key1>
            <key1>201</key1>
        </container>
   </Shipment>
   <Shipment>
        <shipFromLocation>06AC002</shipFromLocation>
        <shipToLocation>08BCDAZ</shipToLocation>
        <container>
            <key1>202</key1>
            <key1>203</key1>
        </container>
   </Shipment>
</Entity>
```

As you can see there 4  tag, within each tag you have `<shipFromLocation>` and `<shipToLocation>`

- The first 2 `<Shipment>` tag contains the same value for `<shipFromLocation>` and `<shipToLocation>`
- The last 2 `<Shipment>` tag contains the same value for `<shipFromLocation>` and `<shipToLocation>`

Now within each `<Shipment>` tag there are multiple `<container>` tag. I'm trying to get a result as follows

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Entity>
   <Shipment>
        <shipFromLocation>06AC001</shipFromLocation>
        <shipToLocation>07BCDAZ</shipToLocation>
        <container>
            <key1>101</key1>
            <key1>102</key1>
        </container>
        <container>
            <key1>103</key1>
            <key1>104</key1>
        </container>
        <container>
            <key1>105</key1>
            <key1>106</key1>
        </container>
        <container>
            <key1>107</key1>
            <key1>108</key1>
        </container>
   </Shipment>
   <Shipment>
        <shipFromLocation>06AC002</shipFromLocation>
        <shipToLocation>08BCDAZ</shipToLocation>
        <container>
            <key1>200</key1>
            <key1>201</key1>
        </container>
        <container>
            <key1>202</key1>
            <key1>203</key1>
        </container>
   </Shipment>

</Entity>
```

That is, you are grouping based on `<shipFromLocation>` and `<shipToLocation>` and aggregating all details in it. I'm failing to generate the XSLT code for it. The one that i've is a broken one

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Entity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Shipment" group-by="shipFromLocation">
        <Shipment>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <shipFromLocation>
                    <xsl:value-of select="shipFromLocation"/>
                </shipFromLocation>
                
                
                    <container>
                        <xsl:value-of select="container"/>
                        
                    </container>

            
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Shipment>
     
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can someone please do help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, you want to do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Entity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Shipment" group-by="concat(shipFromLocation, '|', shipToLocation)">
            <Shipment>
                <xsl:copy-of select="shipFromLocation, shipToLocation"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/container"/>
            </Shipment>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @michael.hor257k, the query helped a lot.