# Group XML Elements by key-tag in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

There is a query for which i am seeing assistance, on how to group the XML by keyElements using XSLT. Below is the sample XML code: -

```
 <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<CISDocument>
    <Aheader>
        <OperationName>APINAME</OperationName>
    </Aheader>
    <ResponseHeader>
        <CompletedSuccessfully>true</CompletedSuccessfully>
    </ResponseHeader>
    <Page>
        <StartAtRow>0</StartAtRow>
        <MaxRows>5</MaxRows>
        <TotalRowCount>1</TotalRowCount>
    </Page>
    <Entity>
        <Load>
            <LID>A</LID>
            <ccode>B</ccode>
            <servicecode>C</servicecode>
            <flocationcode>D</flocationcode>
            <llocationcode>E</llocationcode>
            <BaseShipmentModule>
                <ShipUnitModule>
                    <Shnum>1234567</Shnum>
                    <Sfromlocation>01234</Sfromlocation>
                    <Stolocation>04567</Stolocation>
                    <Container>
                        <SContainerID>1</SContainerID>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        <ContainerVinformation>
                            <Volume>1</Volume>
                        </ContainerVinformation>
                        <ItemNumber>AA</ItemNumber>             
                        <WFClass>
                            <Fweigth>222</Fweigth>
                            <FClassCode>10</FClassCode>
                        </WFClass>
                        <ReferenceNumberStructure>
                            <ReferenceNumberTypeCode>BBB</ReferenceNumberTypeCode>
                            <ReferenceNumber>CCC</ReferenceNumber>
                        </ReferenceNumberStructure>
                        <ReferenceNumberStructure>
                            <ReferenceNumberTypeCode>DDD</ReferenceNumberTypeCode>
                            <ReferenceNumber>1233</ReferenceNumber>
                        </ReferenceNumberStructure>
                    </Container>
                </ShipUnitModule>
            </BaseShipmentModule>
            <BaseShipmentModule>
                <ShipUnitModule>
                    <Shnum>1234568</Shnum>
                    <Sfromlocation>01234</Sfromlocation>
                    <Stolocation>04567</Stolocation>
                    <Container>
                        <SContainerID>1</SContainerID>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        <ContainerVinformation>
                            <Volume>1</Volume>
                        </ContainerVinformation>
                        <ItemNumber>AA</ItemNumber>             
                        <WFClass>
                            <Fweigth>222</Fweigth>
                            <FClassCode>10</FClassCode>
                        </WFClass>
                        <ReferenceNumberStructure>
                            <ReferenceNumberTypeCode>BBB</ReferenceNumberTypeCode>
                            <ReferenceNumber>CCC</ReferenceNumber>
                        </ReferenceNumberStructure>
                        <ReferenceNumberStructure>
                            <ReferenceNumberTypeCode>DDD</ReferenceNumberTypeCode>
                            <ReferenceNumber>1233</ReferenceNumber>
                        </ReferenceNumberStructure>
                    </Container>
                </ShipUnitModule>
            </BaseShipmentModule>
            <BaseShipmentModule>
                <ShipUnitModule>
                    <Shnum>1234569</Shnum>
                    <Sfromlocation>11234</Sfromlocation>
                    <Stolocation>14567</Stolocation>
                    <Container>
                        <SContainerID>1</SContainerID>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        <ContainerVinformation>
                            <Volume>1</Volume>
                        </ContainerVinformation>
                        <ItemNumber>AA</ItemNumber>             
                        <WFClass>
                            <Fweigth>222</Fweigth>
                            <FClassCode>10</FClassCode>
                        </WFClass>
                        <ReferenceNumberStructure>
                            <ReferenceNumberTypeCode>BBB</ReferenceNumberTypeCode>
                            <ReferenceNumber>CCC</ReferenceNumber>
                        </ReferenceNumberStructure>
                        <ReferenceNumberStructure>
                            <ReferenceNumberTypeCode>DDD</ReferenceNumberTypeCode>
                            <ReferenceNumber>1233</ReferenceNumber>
                        </ReferenceNumberStructure>
                    </Container>
                </ShipUnitModule>
            </BaseShipmentModule>
            <BaseShipmentModule>
                <ShipUnitModule>
                    <Shnum>1234570</Shnum>
                    <Sfromlocation>11234</Sfromlocation>
                    <Stolocation>14567</Stolocation>
                    <Container>
                        <SContainerID>1</SContainerID>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        <ContainerVinformation>
                            <Volume>1</Volume>
                        </ContainerVinformation>
                        <ItemNumber>AA</ItemNumber>             
                        <WFClass>
                            <Fweigth>222</Fweigth>
                            <FClassCode>10</FClassCode>
                        </WFClass>
                        <ReferenceNumberStructure>
                            <ReferenceNumberTypeCode>BBB</ReferenceNumberTypeCode>
                            <ReferenceNumber>CCC</ReferenceNumber>
                        </ReferenceNumberStructure>
                        <ReferenceNumberStructure>
                            <ReferenceNumberTypeCode>DDD</ReferenceNumberTypeCode>
                            <ReferenceNumber>1233</ReferenceNumber>
                        </ReferenceNumberStructure>
                    </Container>
                </ShipUnitModule>
            </BaseShipmentModule>   
            <S1>
                <SSID>1613243</SSID>
                <SCount>3</SCount>
                <CDStop>0</CDStop>
                <AATime>2022-06-17T08:00:00</AATime>
                <SLCode>06V0018963</SLCode>
            </S1>
            <S1>
                <SSID>1613244</SSID>
                <SCount>0</SCount>
                <CDStop>16</CDStop>
                <AATime>2022-06-17T19:45:00</AATime>
                <SLCode>06C0124A</SLCode>
            </S1>
            <S1>
                <SSID>1613245</SSID>
                <SCount>4</SCount>
                <CDStop>0</CDStop>
                <AATime>2022-06-17T09:00:00</AATime>
                <SLCode>06V0029699</SLCode>
            </S1>
            
        </Load>
    </Entity>
```

As we can see in the above XML example, there are multiple **BaseShipmentModule tag** and within each BaseShipmentModule we have a tag called: **Sfromlocation and Stolocation** which stands for location code, from and to location.

Now if we observe a little bit, we have a total of 4 **BaseShipmentModule** tag and the value for **Sfromlocation and Stolocation** in same in the 1st and 2nd BaseShipmentModule tag. Where as the value for **Sfromlocation and Stolocation** is same in the 3rd and 4th **BaseShipmentModule** tag. Looking for to group the XML based on the **Sfromlocation and Stolocation**.

Expected output is shown below: -

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<CISDocument>
    <Aheader>
        <OperationName>APINAME</OperationName>
    </Aheader>
    <ResponseHeader>
        <CompletedSuccessfully>true</CompletedSuccessfully>
    </ResponseHeader>
    <Page>
        <StartAtRow>0</StartAtRow>
        <MaxRows>5</MaxRows>
        <TotalRowCount>1</TotalRowCount>
    </Page>
    <Entity>
        <Load>
            <LID>A</LID>
            <ccode>B</ccode>
            <servicecode>C</servicecode>
            <flocationcode>D</flocationcode>
            <llocationcode>E</llocationcode>
            <BaseShipmentModule>
                <ShipUnitModule>
                    <Shnum>1234567</Shnum>
                    <Shnum>1234568</Shnum>
                    <Sfromlocation>01234</Sfromlocation>
                    <Stolocation>04567</Stolocation>
                    <Container>
                        <SContainerID>1</SContainerID>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        <ContainerVinformation>
                            <Volume>1</Volume>
                        </ContainerVinformation>
                        <ItemNumber>AA</ItemNumber>             
                        <WFClass>
                            <Fweigth>222</Fweigth>
                            <FClassCode>10</FClassCode>
                        </WFClass>
                        <ReferenceNumberStructure>
                            <ReferenceNumberTypeCode>BBB</ReferenceNumberTypeCode>
                            <ReferenceNumber>CCC</ReferenceNumber>
                        </ReferenceNumberStructure>
                        <ReferenceNumberStructure>
                            <ReferenceNumberTypeCode>DDD</ReferenceNumberTypeCode>
                            <ReferenceNumber>1233</ReferenceNumber>
                        </ReferenceNumberStructure>
                    </Container>
                    <Container>
                        <SContainerID>1</SContainerID>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        <ContainerVinformation>
                            <Volume>1</Volume>
                        </ContainerVinformation>
                        <ItemNumber>AA</ItemNumber>             
                        <WFClass>
                            <Fweigth>222</Fweigth>
                            <FClassCode>10</FClassCode>
                        </WFClass>
                        <ReferenceNumberStructure>
                            <ReferenceNumberTypeCode>BBB</ReferenceNumberTypeCode>
                            <ReferenceNumber>CCC</ReferenceNumber>
                        </ReferenceNumberStructure>
                        <ReferenceNumberStructure>
                            <ReferenceNumberTypeCode>DDD</ReferenceNumberTypeCode>
                            <ReferenceNumber>1233</ReferenceNumber>
                        </ReferenceNumberStructure>
                    </Container>
                </ShipUnitModule>
            </BaseShipmentModule>
            <BaseShipmentModule>
                <ShipUnitModule>
                    <Shnum>1234569</Shnum>
                    <Shnum>1234570</Shnum>
                    <Sfromlocation>11234</Sfromlocation>
                    <Stolocation>14567</Stolocation>
                    <Container>
                        <SContainerID>1</SContainerID>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        <ContainerVinformation>
                            <Volume>1</Volume>
                        </ContainerVinformation>
                        <ItemNumber>AA</ItemNumber>             
                        <WFClass>
                            <Fweigth>222</Fweigth>
                            <FClassCode>10</FClassCode>
                        </WFClass>
                        <ReferenceNumberStructure>
                            <ReferenceNumberTypeCode>BBB</ReferenceNumberTypeCode>
                            <ReferenceNumber>CCC</ReferenceNumber>
                        </ReferenceNumberStructure>
                        <ReferenceNumberStructure>
                            <ReferenceNumberTypeCode>DDD</ReferenceNumberTypeCode>
                            <ReferenceNumber>1233</ReferenceNumber>
                        </ReferenceNumberStructure>
                    </Container>
                    <Container>
                        <SContainerID>1</SContainerID>
                        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                        <ContainerVinformation>
                            <Volume>1</Volume>
                        </ContainerVinformation>
                        <ItemNumber>AA</ItemNumber>             
                        <WFClass>
                            <Fweigth>222</Fweigth>
                            <FClassCode>10</FClassCode>
                        </WFClass>
                        <ReferenceNumberStructure>
                            <ReferenceNumberTypeCode>BBB</ReferenceNumberTypeCode>
                            <ReferenceNumber>CCC</ReferenceNumber>
                        </ReferenceNumberStructure>
                        <ReferenceNumberStructure>
                            <ReferenceNumberTypeCode>DDD</ReferenceNumberTypeCode>
                            <ReferenceNumber>1233</ReferenceNumber>
                        </ReferenceNumberStructure>
                    </Container>
                </ShipUnitModule>
            </BaseShipmentModule>   
            <S1>
                <SSID>1613243</SSID>
                <SCount>3</SCount>
                <CDStop>0</CDStop>
                <AATime>2022-06-17T08:00:00</AATime>
                <SLCode>06V0018963</SLCode>
            </S1>
            <S1>
                <SSID>1613244</SSID>
                <SCount>0</SCount>
                <CDStop>16</CDStop>
                <AATime>2022-06-17T19:45:00</AATime>
                <SLCode>06C0124A</SLCode>
            </S1>
            <S1>
                <SSID>1613245</SSID>
                <SCount>4</SCount>
                <CDStop>0</CDStop>
                <AATime>2022-06-17T09:00:00</AATime>
                <SLCode>06V0029699</SLCode>
            </S1>
            
        </Load>
    </Entity>
```

As we can see in the above result, we have combined the **ShipUnitModule** based on the **Sfromlocation and Stolocation tag**. And he tag **Container** has been grouped and the rest of the **tag S1** is unaffected by it.

We did get help from one of the Engineers (Michael), with the below XSLT,

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Entity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Shipment" group-by="concat(shipFromLocation, '|', shipToLocation)">
            <Shipment>
                <xsl:copy-of select="shipFromLocation, shipToLocation"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/container"/>
            </Shipment>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But, it is not able to help the overall output, please do help us here. Its quite important. Any suggestion will matter a lot.

[image]

Comment: Start by editing your question to ensure you use markdown on your inline snippets so that sentences start to make sense and don't read e.g. "we have a tag called: and which stands "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tha adaptation from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72704700/group-xml-key-tag-with-same-value-using-xslt) is rather trivial, even if tedious:

**XSL 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Load">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="* except (BaseShipmentModule | S1)"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="BaseShipmentModule" group-by="concat(ShipUnitModule/Sfromlocation, '|', ShipUnitModule/Stolocation)">
            <BaseShipmentModule>
                <ShipUnitModule>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/ShipUnitModule/Shnum"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="ShipUnitModule/(Sfromlocation, Stolocation)"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/ShipUnitModule/Container"/>
                </ShipUnitModule>
            </BaseShipmentModule>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        <xsl:copy-of select="S1"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi michael.hor257k, Ive edited the question as you asked. Please let me know if I was clear enough. Sincere apologies for the confusion caused.

Comment: I did not ask you to edit your question. Does my answer not work for you as expected?